# Lineage 2 Freya, doesnt run from wine

Tags: 11.10

I start the game and I get to the login screen. However, all the text on the login screen is gone. 
Could this be my video card? Shall install the video card driver using wine? 
Or is this DirectX? Do you guys think that I should install it using wine too?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this could be because you dont have the correct fonts installed in

```
~/.wine/drive_c/windows/fonts
```

Try to find out what fonts the game uses and install them in the mentioned directory.

Comment: wow.....thanks a lot for the super fast answer. I look into it ASAP  and get back to you. Cheers.

Comment: By the way...Messie, how do I know what the correct fonts are?

Comment: SOLUTION: ok, got the problem sorted. Use "winetricks" and install all the fonts there. This sorts out the text problem.
Special thanks to Messie!!! :)